# runing a query of combinationfield in runtime,how?

Tags: ms-access

I have a combination field that contains a query.I want to speed up my access forms hence I want to run the query of this combinationfield in runtime( in VB code) but I dont know how? Would you please show me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want a `SELECT` query then use

```
    Dim recSet As Recordset
    recSet = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE field1=" & Me.myField)
```

or

```
    recSet = DoCmd.RunSQL("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE field1=" & Me.myField)
```

for other commands (`DELETE`, `UPDATE`, `INSERT`,...) use

```
    CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE * FROM table1 WHERE field1=" & Me.myField
```

or

```
    DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM table1 WHERE field1=" & Me.myField
```